# Nodejs + Node-Sqlite3 Installation Problem

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I installed nodejs and it is working. I then downloaded node-sqlite3 from https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3. When I try to configure it I get a message stating that the node path was not found.

**Checking for node path : not found**

at the end it states that configure finished successfully. I rebooted the machine but this did not solve the problem, and I can't find a solution by online.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 0):

check your local path environment variable. Is the path to your node binary on the path? You probably just need to add it to the path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I assume it is in my path as I can execute node from my dev directory.

Comment: that is no way to tell if it's in your path. try typing env at your command line.