# Trouble with using a sqlite module for node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, node-gyp

[I tried to include more links to make my questions more clear but stackoverflow wouldn't let me because I do not have 10 reputation points.]

I have node.js and now I want to choose a sqlite module for it and my choices are: orlandov/node-sqlite, developmentseed/node-sqlite3, and grumdrig/node-sqlite.  I eliminated grumdrig because only synchronous access is supported.

When I tried to explore developmentseed by following their directions,  I encounter this problem:

```
./configure

./configure: line 3: node-gyp: command not found
```

So I tried to use npm install (also suggested) and encounter this problem:

```
npm install sqlite3
-bash: npm: command not found
```

When I tried to get npm with

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

I encounter this problem (even with sudo and changing owner/permission):

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    85    0    85    0     0    175      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

**sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'**

sh: line 1: `<html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'
```

I looked at stackoverflow's: [Node.js : NPM Install Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752873/node-js-npm-install-fails) and [Nodejs + Node-Sqlite3 Installation Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077628/nodejs-node-sqlite3-installation-problem) and many other links but haven't found a solution.

I am also having trouble configuring node-sqlite by orlandov.

I just wanted to play around with node-sqlite (by orlandov) and node-sqlite3 (by developmentseed) so I can choose the better one but am stuck here.

Oh, I also looked into node-gyp at github -- /TooTallNate/node-gyp/ but it seems to also need npm.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to get these to build and/or which to use between developmentseed and orlandov's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install npm directly use this command:

```
curl -k https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

If you use Ubuntu you can install lastest versions of node.js and npm from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/). **Note**: you need to remove your current nodejs first.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm
```

Install node-gyp:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

Now you ready to install sqlite3 from npm.

```
npm install sqlite3
```

**Note**: build tools need to be installed before sqlite3 setup.

For ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I was able to install npm.  I already have the latest version of node.js.  I installed node-gyp.  When I tried to do: npm install sqlite3, I get this error: npm WARN install Refusing to install sqlite3 as a dependency of itself
so I did the sudo apt -get install build-essential and then I tried again but still have the same error.  Do you know why that may be?  Does it matter where node-sqlite3 is in relation to the node.js folder?  Right now, I have both folders in a folder called project-node.  Does the sqlite3 folder need to be IN the node.js folder?  Thank you so much.

Comment: npm modules may be installed to any folders. It's not important. Try to install libsqlite3-dev. sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev. If it fails again post full npm error log here.

Comment: Oops, when I did sudo apt -get install build-essential I got this error:  apt: invalid flag: -get and I get the same error when I did sudo apt -get install libsqlite3-dev.  If i do apt-get without the space, I see: sudo: apt-get: command not found so I probably still don't have the build tools properly installed.  Hm, ...

Comment: apt-get (only without space) is a debian like (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint etc.) only OS package manager. If you are using other OS like Gentoo or MacOS, you need to use your OS package manager.

Comment: Is there a way to check if I already have the build tools installed?  After I configure and make sqlite3, I have to use npm install to install it right?  Is there any other way?  Is it already usable?  Do you know if this error: npm WARN install Refusing to install sqlite3 as a dependency of itself  is a result of not havnig the build tools installed?  Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In case this did not work for some, here is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt install node-sqlite3
```

*(I was trying to install sqlite3 for Ubuntu in order to work with nodejs and sqlite3 database (editor used is vscode). Even though I tried npm and sudo apt to install sqlite3, it kept giving an error "Module not found")*